# setAttribute and getElementById

Tags: javascript

When I do this:

```
col = document.createElement("div");
col.setAttribute("id", "col" + ii);
alert(document.getElementById("col" + ii));
```

alert displays null. How can I get setAttribute to have an effect?

Comment: You havent added the element to the DOM, `document.body.appendChild(col)` first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an element with `document.createElement`, it creates the element but does not add it to the DOM. To add it to DOM you have to use `appendChild` method on the element inside which you want your new element to be.

Let us assume that you want to add your new `div` at end of the `body`. Try the following code.

```
col = document.createElement("div");
col.setAttribute("id", "col" + ii);
document.body.appendChild(col)
alert(document.getElementById("col" + ii));
```